# Cloud Storage - Get actual creation date of a file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Whenever I upload a file to my Cloud Storage bucket, I expect it to conserve the actual date that file was created. However, whenever I access the file through the storage client API on Python, and check the `generation` metadata field of the blob, it displays the date when that file was uploaded to the storage.

These are the steps to reproduce:

```
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucketname)
blob = bucket.get_blob(filename)
creation_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(blob.generation/(10**6)).date()
```

Is there a way to get the actual generation date of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata are system generated on Google Cloud side. So yes, the date of the file on Cloud Storage is the beginning of the existence of the file on this system: the upload date.

To solve your issue, you need more code. You can rename the file with its date of generation. Or you can use [custom metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata) on the blob to add this information

Comment: Custom metadata is a nice feature to take into account, thanks for sharing. However, the file is uploaded by one of the team members on a drag and drop basis. Is there a way to access the original file metadata once it is uploaded to the bucket?

Comment: Sadly not, only the content is sent to Cloud Storage, not the metadata of the file in your file system.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I get the created date using Python

```
import google.cloud.storage

client = google.cloud.storage.Client.from_service_account_json('key_path')
l_bucket_name = "bucketName"
l_bucket = client.get_bucket(l_bucket_name)
strPrefix = 'filter_string'
for o in l_bucket.list_blobs(prefix=strPrefix):
  print(o.updated)  # This gives last update time, in my case it is the created time
```

Best regards,